# An easy way to ensure the right sequence in forEach / for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach, waterfall

I have the following function in my node.js app which loops through an array and performs a certain function on it:

```
var splitStatements = ['1','2','3']; // this is simplified

splitStatements.forEach(function(statement) {  

    // `statement` is written into the database 
    // the response is obtained and modified as `response`

    console.log(response);

});
```

How do I ensure that no matter how complex the function inside the `forEach` function is, each element of the array would be processed one by one, so that the result output is something like

```
1 modified
2 modified
3 modified
```

In reality I sometimes get something like

```
1 modified
3 modified
2 modified
```

Depending on how complex each element of `splitStatements` array is.

I understand that the above happens because the code execution is  asynchronous, so what is the best practice way to ensure that while it is executed asynchronously each next procedure ensures that the previous one has been performed already in order to be started?

Comment: Async.js has convenient methods for doing this.

Comment: `response = await database.write(statement)`

Answer (score 2):

If the order you insert the data in really matters, then you need to wait for each query to finish before sending the next one.

Don't use a for loop.

Write a function which sets the *next* item in the array to the database. Call that function once directly, and then again inside the callback that indicates the asynchronous database call is complete.

Include a test so you stop when you run out of items in the array!

If you don't need to preserve the contents of the array, you can use `arr.unshift()` to get the next item. If you don't get a result, you have reached the end.

If you need to preserve the array, then use a variable (traditionally `i`) to keep track of which array index you are at. Increment it by one each time.

```
function insert_into_database() {
    var item = arr.unshift();
    if (item) {
        add_to_database(item).then(insert_into_database);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your not structured array from database, issue not in `forEach`

You need to send query to database with sort or order options

Comment: or order it yourself when you get it from the database, however, that is rarely prudent.

Comment: @MortenBork sorting in code after DB response is not correct, you should write SQL query with pagination and ordering

Comment: @alex dykyi

so if I am writing a query that is being used by many different interfaces, I have to build them pre-ordered? what kind of nonsense is that?

It depends on the what the result is going to be used for. That is way to broad a statement to make. What if pagination isn't even required? Should I still implement it then?

Comment: @MortenBork pagination is not required, but for many queries it's good for use if you have big lists of your data from DB

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I simply timestamp every `statement` that enters into the database adding a few milliseconds to each (that equals this statement's position inside the array). So if it's 1st, I add 1, if it's 2nd I add 2, etc.

Then when I extract those statements from the database I simply sort them by this timestamp (which was already the case).